# How to deploy ReactJS web application on a windows server using Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows-server-2008-r2

I have developed a ReactJS app using the create-react-app on my local windows 10 machine..

Now, I want to deploy this application on a on-premise windows 2008 R2 server. I do not have much experience with this. When I searched over the internet, all the articles are talking about either deploying into IIS or in cloud. But, I do not want to use IIS and I have On-Premise server.

Is there any other way to deploy and host this ReactJS application on Windows server machine? Maybe just using the Node.JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the **build** using `npm run build` and write a `nodejs` script with `express` to serve the build directory.

The `nodejs` script would be like this:

***start-server.js***

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const basePath = '';
const app = express();

app.use(basePath + "/", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + "/build")));

app.get("*", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + "/build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(port);
```

To start the server:

```
node start-server.js
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But, I had to add 'var app = express();' line to make it work..

Comment: Oops! Of course, `app` should be initialized, don't know how that was missed. Fixed. Thanks and cheers!